# My text bounding rectangle

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d

From the following code, we can get the bounding rectangle of our text:

```
Graphics2D twoD = (Graphics2D) g;
FontRenderContext frc = twoD.getFontRenderContext();
Rectangle2D textBound = myFont.getStringBounds(myText, frc);
```

but in core java textbook, it says that

> the rectangle has its origin at the
>   baseline of the string, and the top
>   y-coordinate of the rectangle is
>   negative.

What is that mean, why the top y-coordinate is negative?

And any more clarification to this concept is highly appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you measure text, there is no concept of where you are drawing it. So they make the somewhat arbitrary, but i suppose sensible decision that the point (0, 0) is at the baseline of the text, to the left of the first character.

This is good because if you were to say

```
void drawSomeText(Graphics g, String sample) {
    g.drawString(sample, 0, 0);
}
```

it would fit in the box that measure text told you about.

Given that the ascent of the text goes more and more negative, while the descenders occupy positive *y* space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i got the idea of text being drawn arbitrary now, but why are you saying that descenders occupy positive x space, instead of y space just bellow the baseline.

Comment: +1 An API [note](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) calls these _baseline-relative coordinates_.

Comment: The picture from [`FontMetrics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) is nice, too.

Comment: That's ok MeBigFatGuy, Thank so much for your explanation